# Различие между ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE и ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc, h2

Доброго времени суток.

Как я понял `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, в отличии от `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, чувствителен к изменениям, которые произошли с базой данных после создания объекта `ResultSet`. Но я не могу понять, что означает "чувствителен к изменениям".

Я пробовал создавать `ResultSet` с типом `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` и в течении 10 секунд запрашивать первую строку таблицы:

```
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select * from numbers");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result.absolute(1);
    System.out.printf("number=%d name=%s\n",
                    result.getInt("number"), result.getString("name"));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

В тоже время запускать второй поток в котором каждые 500 миллисекунд менять первую строку этой же таблицы:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    String sql = String.format("UPDATE NUMBERS SET number=%d WHERE id=1",
                    (int) (Math.random() * 900_000_000));
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Я ожидал, что вносимые изменения увидит `ResultSet` из первого потока, но это не так. Объект ResultSet созданный с типом `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` ведет себя точно также.

Объясните пожалуйста, в чем тогда заключается разница между этими двумя типами `ResultSet`.

P.s. использую СУБД H2.

Comment: Почему бы не почитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)?

Comment: В цикле повторите statement.executeQuery("select * from numbers") и тогда вы увидите изменения.

Comment: Roman C - смотрел, и все что у меня получилось найти, это: The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is scrollable and generally sensitive to changes to the data that underlies the ResultSet. Вопрос это не проясняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean supportsResultSetType(int type) {
    debugCodeCall("supportsResultSetType", type);
    return type != ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE;
}
```

[Драйвер H2 не поддерживает TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE.](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcDatabaseMetaData.java#L2398)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я проверил драйвер MySql с помощью этого метода на поддержку TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE. Оказалось он тоже не поддерживает этот тип ResultSet. Могли бы вы назвать СУБД поддерживающую TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE?

Comment: Попробуйте оракл. Постгре тоже не поддерживает (изначально на постгре пробовал)

Comment: Проверил, оракл действительно поддерживает.

Comment: Большое спасибо.